# How do I create a custom element using a JS class to create the properties for the element

Tags: javascript, html, class, custom-element

So I know how to create a custom element and have 2 already made that I'm happy with.
My two elems look something like this:

```
let menuPicker = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

menuPicker.initialized = false;
menuPicker._init = function(){
...
}
...
menuPicker.attachedCallback = menuPicker._init;
menuPicker.createdCallback = menuPicker._init;
...
document.registerElement('menu-picker', {
    prototype: menuPicker
});
```

Which works and all, but this time around I want a JS *class*. Specifically this feature:

```
class test {
    get item(){...}
    set item(){...}
}
```

So I figured I could just do the following to easily implement this.

```
class listBox extends HTMLElement.prototype {
    initialized = false;
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.attachedCallback = this._init;
        this.createdCallback = this._init;
    }
    _init () {
        if(this.initialized) return;
        this.initialized = true;
        this.style.display = "block";
        this.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    }
}
document.registerElement('list-box', {
    prototype: listBox
});
```

However I get the error `Class extends value #<HTMLElement> is not a constructor or null`.
So now I'm stuck and can't find a method of using a class to construct a custom HTML element.

To simplify:

> How do I create a custom element using a JS class to create the properties for the element?

Comment: This feels like a question that could have been avoided by reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Comment: oml :P I did read that very article when I was first learning how to create elements. TYSM for re-directing me there. I feel like an idiot.

Comment: it happens sometimes. Probably worth deleting the question again =)

Comment: The error is caused by the line `class listBox extends HTMLElement.prototype`. It should be `class listBox extends HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to create a custom element

```
  //ListBox.js
  export default class ListBox extends HTMLElement {
  // observe attributes of custom element
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["disp", "text"];
  }

  get myAction() {
    return this.hasAttribute("open");
  }

  set myAction(val) {
    if (val) {
      this.setAttribute("open", "");
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute("open");
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.initialized = false;
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    // get and assigns value from props "disp"
    this.div.style.display = this.getAttribute("disp");
    // get and assigns value from props "text"
    this.div.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("text");
    this.appendChild(this.div);
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    // didMount
    // your methode here
    this.initialized = true;
    console.log("custom element added to page");
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    // unmount
    console.log("custom element remove from page");
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    // observed props
    console.log("props", arguments);
    // get and assigns value from props "text"
    if (name === "text" && oldValue !== newValue) {
      this.div.innerHTML = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

in your html in the script tag which calls your index.js add type="module"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <list-box text="Some text here" disp="block"></list-box>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your index.js import your component and do Something

```
import ListBox from "./component/ListBox";

customElements.define("list-box", ListBox);

// change props "text value"
document
  .querySelector("list-box")
  .setAttribute("text", `Change the value of props "text"`);
```